# Batch File - Loop using xcopy with variable number of Variables?

Tags: loops, batch-file, xcopy

I'm a paralegal, and need to create folders and files for each contract that comes in.  The folders will be named to only the address, and inside there will be 2 empty folders, and 2 prepared files, a DOCX and a TXT which need to be amended with the address in the name.  I keep an example folder named simply "@" so that it stays at the top of the list of folders.  I wrote a script to copy rename things as I need them:

```
xcopy "@" "$VAR1" /e /i
cd "$VAR1"
rename "Deed - Blank.docx" "Deed - $VAR1.docx"
rename "Deed Prep.txt" "$VAR1 Deed Prep.txt"
cd..
```

This saves some time, but so far, whenever I need to use it, I copy it into a NotePad window, then use Control+H to replace all instances of "$VAR1" with the address.  I then copy the base script again, and Control+H with the new address.  When I have everything, I open a Command Window to the root folder, and paste the commands.  Sometimes we get 3 new contracts, sometimes 10, but things are generally picking up, so I know I need to make it a proper Loop to save a lot more time.

From searching, I now know that the pieces I need are `set /p` and `for /l` but..  I just don't know how to put the pieces together.  I need to be able to input the addresses somehow, so whether it's being prompted one at a time, or all at once, or entering them in the main command, like `script.bat "123 Happy St" "1600 Pennsylvania Ave" "32 John's Wall Dr"` that would be much better than how I do it now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: rather than editing the script with new values, replace the variable values with Argument references `%1` , `%2` etc and call the script from the command prompt with the relevent arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
:again
set "property=%~1"
if not defined property goto :eof

xcopy "@" "%property%" /e /i
cd "%property%"
rename "Deed - Blank.docx" "Deed - %property%.docx"
rename "Deed Prep.txt" "%property% Deed Prep.txt"
cd..

shift
goto again
```

The first two lines 1) suppress `echo` ing of the commands executed to the console and 2) make sure that any changes to the environment are backed out when the batch ends. This ensures that successive batch files don't interact due to variables established in a prior batch run in the same session.

The label `again` is simply a return-point (colon is required)

the `set` command gets the first argument, removes its surrounding quotes, and assigns the result to the variable `property`.

If there are no further arguments, `property` will be unassigned, so exit the batch (the colon is required)

Then in your routine, use the value of `property` within the commands by surrounding the variablename with `%`.

Finally, `shift` the arguments - discard %1 and shuffle the remained along, so %2 becomes %1, etc.

Then you can run the batch as `script.bat "123 Happy St" "1600 Pennsylvania Ave" "32 John's Wall Dr"`

Comment: Wow.  This is a thing of beauty.  I knew I was close, but there were pieces I was missing..  Thank you so much, Magoo, for putting it together.  I just tried it, and it works absolutely flawlessly.  Thank you!!